# Can I join two files by a matching column in fortran?

Tags: file, join, fortran

I am new at using fortran.
Can I somehow join two datafiles by matching columns?

I am trying to join two data files. The first one has 100.000 records where each line represents one person. The second file has 400.000 records where a person in the first file can appear multiple times. The first column in both files has a unique ID of each person

I want to join the files by the first column and add information from file 1 to file 2... so the new file will have 400.000 lines with added information about each person from datafile1.

**This is the code I have tried writing:**

```
integer, parameter :: nosaed=411684!saedingar 411684

integer, parameter :: noeinst=105161 !gripir 105161

integer, dimension(1:nosaed) :: einsts, saeding, frjot

integer, dimension(1:noeinst) :: einstg, bu, faeding, forgun, burdur1, burdur2, burdur3, burdur4

integer :: i, j

character (len=21):: pth

 pth="home/thordis/frjosemi"

open (unit=10, file=pth//"saedingar.txt", status="old")

open (unit=11, file=pth//"gripalisti.txt", status="old")

open (unit=12, file=pth//"gagnasafn.txt", status="new")


do j = 1, noeinst
  read (11,1011) einstg(j), bu(j), faeding(j), forgun(j), burdur1(j), burdur2(j), burdur3(j), burdur4(j)

  1011 format (i15,2x,i6,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8)

do i = 1, nosaed

  read (10,1010) einsts(i), saeding(i), frjot(i)

  1010 format (i15,1x,i8,1x,i3)


if (einsts == einstg) then

  write (12,1012) einsts, saeding, frjot, bu, faeding, forgun, &

                burdur1, burdur2, burdur3, burdur4

  1012 format (i15,1x,i8,1x,i3,1x,i6,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8)

        endif


enddo
enddo
```

When I try to compile it get this message:

```
if (einsts == einstg) then
    1        2
Error: Shapes for operands at (1) and (2) are not conformable
```

Is this because the datafiles are not the same lenght?
Is it possible to do what I was trying to do in Fortran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work!

```
integer,parameter :: k15 = selected_int_kind(15)

integer, parameter :: nosaed=411684 !saedingar 411684
integer, parameter :: noeinst=105161 !gripir 105161


integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:nosaed) :: einsts
integer, dimension(1:nosaed) :: saeding, frjot

integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:noeinst) :: einstg
integer, dimension(1:noeinst) :: bu, faeding, forgun, burdur1, burdur2, &
                                  burdur3, burdur4
    
integer :: i, j

character (len=21):: pth

pth="home/thordis/frjosemi"

open (unit=10, file=pth//"saedingar.txt", status="old")
do i = 1, nosaed
  read (10,1010) einsts(i), saeding(i), frjot(i)

  1010 format (i15,1x,i8,1x,i3)
enddo

open (unit=11, file=pth//"gripalisti.txt", status="old")
do j = 1, noeinst
  read (11,1011) einstg(j), bu(j), faeding(j), forgun(j), burdur1(j), burdur2(j), & 
burdur3(j), burdur4(j)

  1011 format (i15,2x,i7,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8)
enddo

open (unit=12, file=pth//"gagnasafn.txt", status="new")
do j = 1, noeinst
  do i = 1, nosaed
    if (einsts(i) == einstg(j)) then
      write (12,1012) einsts(i), saeding(i), frjot(i), bu(j), faeding(j), &
  forgun(j), burdur1(j), burdur2(j), burdur3(j), burdur4(j)
  1012 format (i15,1x,i8,1x,i3,1x,i7,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8)
    endif
  enddo
enddo
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `einsts==einstg` is trying to compare the two arrays element-wise, but the arrays are of different lengths so this doesn't work. Instead, you want to compare the relevant elements, using `einsts(i)==einstg(j)`.

One thing I should point out: you are currently reading `saedingar.txt` `105161` times. This is likely to be quite slow. Instead, I would recommend reading the file once and then looping over the data multiple times, e.g. as:

```
integer, parameter :: nosaed=411684 !saedingar 411684

integer, parameter :: noeinst=105161 !gripir 105161

integer, dimension(1:nosaed) :: einsts, saeding, frjot

integer, dimension(1:noeinst) :: einstg, bu, faeding, forgun, burdur1, burdur2, burdur3, burdur4

integer :: i, j

character (len=21):: pth

pth="home/thordis/frjosemi"

open (unit=10, file=pth//"saedingar.txt", status="old")
do i = 1, nosaed
  read (10,1010) einsts(i), saeding(i), frjot(i)

  1010 format (i15,1x,i8,1x,i3)
enddo

open (unit=11, file=pth//"gripalisti.txt", status="old")
do j = 1, noeinst
  read (11,1011) einstg(j), bu(j), faeding(j), forgun(j), burdur1(j), burdur2(j), burdur3(j), burdur4(j)

  1011 format (i15,2x,i6,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8,2x,i8)
enddo

open (unit=12, file=pth//"gagnasafn.txt", status="new")
do j = 1, noeinst
  do i = 1, nosaed
    if (einsts(i) == einstg(j)) then
      write (12,1012) einsts(i), saeding(i), frjot(i), &
          & bu(j), faeding(j), forgun(j), burdur1(j), burdur2(j), burdur3(j), burdur4(j)

      1012 format (i15,1x,i8,1x,i3,1x,i6,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i8)
    endif
  enddo
enddo
```

Comment: Thank so much for this! I also added (i) and (j) to each element in the write command and then it worked!