# Adding information to file by ID in column in Fortran

Tags: join, merge, fortran, do-loops

I am trying to combine multiple files in Fortran.
The files all have one column in common ("einst")

The main file has over 100.000 lines but the other files contain extra info about some of the IDs in the main file.

I want to merge the smaller files into the large file and keep all the IDs from the large file that did not get extra information from the smaller files.

I previously asked a similar question...
[Can I join two files by a matching column in fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406528/can-i-join-two-files-by-a-matching-column-in-fortran)
..... And had great success but with that code BUT, IDs that are NOT in BOTH data files will not appear in the new merged data file.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
program sameining2
implicit none


integer,parameter :: k15 = selected_int_kind(15)

integer, parameter :: noeinst=25 !LARGE FILE  
integer, parameter :: nosaed_k=3 !SMALL FILE
integer, parameter :: nosaed_1=3 !SMALL FILE
integer, parameter :: nosaed_2=3 !SMALL FILE
integer, parameter :: nosaed_3=3 !SMALL FILE

!COLUMNS IN LARGE FILE
integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:noeinst) :: einstg
integer, dimension(1:noeinst) :: bu, faeding, forgun

!COLUMNS IN SMALL FILE, firstlastkvigur
integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:nosaed_k) :: einst_k
integer, dimension(1:nosaed_k) :: frjot_k, fyrstasaed_k, &
                                    fjoldisaed_k, sidastasaed_k

!COLUMNS IN SMALL FILE, firstlastmjalt1
integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:nosaed_1) :: einst_1
integer, dimension(1:nosaed_1) :: frjot_1, fyrstasaed_1, &
                                    fjoldisaed_1, sidastasaed_1
!COLUMNS IN SMALL FILE, firstlastmjalt2
integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:nosaed_2) :: einst_2
integer, dimension(1:nosaed_2) :: frjot_2, fyrstasaed_2, &
                                    fjoldisaed_2, sidastasaed_2
!COLUMNS IN SMALL FILE, firstlastmjalt3
integer(kind=k15), dimension(1:nosaed_3) :: einst_3
integer, dimension(1:nosaed_3) :: frjot_3, fyrstasaed_3, &
                                    fjoldisaed_3, sidastasaed_3

integer :: i, j, k, m, n

!------------------------------------
!READING THE LARGE FILE
open (unit=11, file="gripalistis.txt", status="old")
do k = 1, noeinst
  read (11,1011) einstg(k), bu(k), faeding(k), forgun(k)
  1011 format (i15,1x,i7,1x,i8,1x,i8)
enddo
close (11, status="keep")

!READING THE SMALL FILE
open (unit=20000, file="firstlastkvigur.txt", status="old")
do i = 1, nosaed_k
read (20000,1017) einst_k(i), frjot_k(i), fyrstasaed_k(i), sidastasaed_k(i), &
            fjoldisaed_k(i)
enddo

!READING THE SMALL FILE
open (unit=30000, file="firstlastmjalt1.txt", status="old")
do j = 1, nosaed_1
read (30000,1017) einst_1(j), frjot_1(j), fyrstasaed_1(j), sidastasaed_1(j), &
            fjoldisaed_1(j)
enddo
!READING THE SMALL FILE
open (unit=40000, file="firstlastmjalt2.txt", status="old")
do m = 1, nosaed_2
read (40000,1017) einst_2(m), frjot_2(m), fyrstasaed_2(m), sidastasaed_2(m), &
            fjoldisaed_2(m)
enddo
!READING THE SMALL FILE
open (unit=50000, file="firstlastmjalt3.txt", status="old")
do n = 1, nosaed_3
read (50000,1017) einst_3(n), frjot_3(n), fyrstasaed_3(n), sidastasaed_3(n), &
            fjoldisaed_3(n)
enddo

close (20000, status="keep")
close (30000, status="keep")
close (40000, status="keep")
close (50000, status="keep")
!------------------------------------

open (unit=80, file=pth//"alldata.txt", status="new")



!This program does not work and it only starts with the first two files...
! HERE I AM TRYING TO TELL THE PROGRAM TO WRITE ALL INFORMATION NEW AND OLD IF 
!THE IDs match, AND ELSE IT SHOULD JUST PRINT THE INFO FROM THE LARGE FILE
!------------------------------------

do i = no, nosaed_k
do k = 1, noeinst

if (einst_kf(i) == einstg(k)  ) then
write (80,1018) einstg(k), bu(k), faeding(k), forgun(k)
frjot_k(i), fyrstasaed_k(i), sidastasaed_k(i), fjoldisaed_k(i)

else
  write (80,1018) einstg(k), bu(k), faeding(k), forgun(k)

endif

1018 format (i15,1x,i7,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x &
i3,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i2,1x &
i8,1x,i8,1x,i2 )

enddo
enddo

close (80, status="keep")

1017 format (i15,1x,i3,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i2)

endprogram sameining2
```

But what happens is that the do loop compares the first ID in the first file to all the ID in the second file and just writes it over and over again and I get a very large wrong file.

I am not skilled enough to write do loops that compare the IDs from both files, writes information from both files if there is a match but if there is not a match in the small file it only writes information that was already in the large file.

My main goal is actually to try to combine 4 smaller files into the large data file and end up with the same amount of IDs as the original large file but all the extra information in the small files has merged to matching IDs.
But the code above only attempts to merge two files.
**Edit**:
I have added types for all the 5 files and below there are previews of the files. I have not edited the do loop I tried to make.
My final goal is a file with this information:

```
einstg(k), bu(k), faeding(k), forgun(k),
frjot_k(i), fyrstasaed_k(i), sidastasaed_k(i), fjoldisaed_k(i),
frjot_1(j), fyrstasaed_1(j), sidastasaed_1(j), fjoldisaed_1(j), 
frjot_2(m), fyrstasaed_2(m), sidastasaed_2(m), fjoldisaed_2(m), 
frjot_3(n), fyrstasaed_3(n), sidastasaed_3(n), fjoldisaed_3(n)
```

Help with my problem would be very much appreciated!

**Edit**:
Preview of the files:

```
gripalisti.txt
200716619210513 1661921 20070309 20101012  
200716619210514 1661921 20070317 20120919 
200716619210515 1661921 20070425 20110208  
200716619210521 1661921 20070730 20121211        
200716619210522 1661921 20070812 20131125
200716619210525 1661921 20071114 20141121 
200716619210526 1661921 20071123 20140205 
200716619210530 1661921 20071223 20101129                                    
200716619510154 1661951 20070201 20131115 
200716619510156 1661951 20070203 20090709                                    
200716619510157 1661951 20070203 20110715        
200716619510158 1661951 20070215 20100611                                    
200716619510159 1661951 20070322 20181116
200716619510160 1661951 20070525 20150807 
200716619510161 1661951 20070526 20090417
200816385110263 1638511 20080514 20170629           
200816385110267 1638511 20080806 20170127 
200816385110268 1638511 20080827 20170725 
200816385110276 1638511 20081112 20121120                
200816386010531 1638881 20080207 20130314      
200816386010532 1637551 20080213 20131107      
200816386010533 1638601 20080213 20120224                 
200816386010543 1638601 20080305 20100901                        
200816386010544 1638601 20080306 20101015                         
200816386010546 1638921 20080311 20160113 

firstlastkvigur.txt
200716619210513  32 20090309 20091218  6
200816386010531  60 20091013 20091013  1
200816386010546  89 20091215 20100113  3


firstlastmjalt1.txt
200716619210521  32 20111218 20111218  1
200716619210525 162 20101207 20101207  1
200816386010533  60 20100928 20101019  2

firstlastmjalt2.txt
200716619510154  10 20130612 20130724  5
200716619510159  10 20120612 20120715  1
200816386010533  10 20110612 20150722  1

firstlastmjalt3.txt
200716619210513  34 20111218 20111218  7
200716619210526  34 20091215 20100113  2
200716619510158  54 20100928 20101019  2
```

Comment: Thanks @jack I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you want is this:

```
module m
  implicit none
  
  integer, parameter :: k15 = selected_int_kind(15)
  
  type :: EinstData
    integer(k15) :: einst
    integer      :: bu
    integer      :: faeding
    integer      :: forgun
  end type
  
  type :: SaedData
    integer(k15) :: einst
    integer      :: frjot
    integer      :: fyrstasaed
    integer      :: sidastasaed
    integer      :: fjoldisaed
  end type
contains
end module

program p
  use m
  implicit none
  
  character(14), parameter :: einst_filename    = 'gripalisti.txt'
  integer,       parameter :: einst_size        = 25
  character(19), parameter :: saed_filenames(3) = [ 'firstlastkvigur.txt', &
                                                  & 'firstlastmjalt1.txt', &
                                                  & 'firstlastmjalt2.txt'  ]
  integer,       parameter :: saed_sizes(3)     = [3, 3, 3]
  
  type(EinstData) :: einst(1:einst_size)
  type(SaedData)  :: saed
  type(SaedData)  :: einst_saed(1:einst_size)
  logical         :: einst_has_saed(1:einst_size)
  
  character(23) :: einst_format = '(i15,1x,i7,1x,i8,1x,i8)'
  character(25) :: saed_format  = '(1x,i3,1x,i8,1x,i8,1x,i2)'
  
  integer :: i,j,k
  
  ! Read the main file.
  open(unit=11, file=einst_filename, status='old')
  do i=1,einst_size
    read(11,*) einst(i)%einst,   &
             & einst(i)%bu,      &
             & einst(i)%faeding, &
             & einst(i)%forgun
  enddo
  close(11)
  
  ! Read each small file in turn.
  einst_has_saed = .false.
  do i=1,3
    open(unit=11, file=saed_filenames(i), status='old')
    do j=1,saed_sizes(j)
      read(11,*) saed%einst,       &
               & saed%frjot,       &
               & saed%fyrstasaed,  &
               & saed%sidastasaed, &
               & saed%fjoldisaed
      ! Find the matching line from the main file.
      ! If found, set einst_saed(k) and set einst_has_saed(k) to true.
      do k=1,einst_size
        if (einst(k)%einst==saed%einst) then
          einst_saed(k) = saed
          einst_has_saed(k) = .true.
        endif
      enddo
    enddo
    close(11)
  enddo
  
  ! Write the output file.
  open(unit=11, file='alldata.txt', status='new')
  do i=1,einst_size
    write(11, einst_format, advance='no') einst(i)%einst,   &
                                        & einst(i)%bu,      &
                                        & einst(i)%faeding, &
                                        & einst(i)%forgun
    if (einst_has_saed(i)) then
      write(11, saed_format, advance='no') einst_saed(i)%frjot,       &
                                         & einst_saed(i)%fyrstasaed,  &
                                         & einst_saed(i)%sidastasaed, &
                                         & einst_saed(i)%fjoldisaed
    endif
    write(11, *)
  enddo
  close(11)
end program
```

which produces alldata.txt:

```
200716619210513 1661921 20070309 20101012
200716619210514 1661921 20070317 20120919
200716619210515 1661921 20070425 20110208
200716619210521 1661921 20070730 20121211  32 20111218 20111218  1
200716619210522 1661921 20070812 20131125
200716619210525 1661921 20071114 20141121 162 20101207 20101207  1
200716619210526 1661921 20071123 20140205
200716619210530 1661921 20071223 20101129
200716619510154 1661951 20070201 20131115
200716619510156 1661951 20070203 20090709
200716619510157 1661951 20070203 20110715
200716619510158 1661951 20070215 20100611
200716619510159 1661951 20070322 20181116
200716619510160 1661951 20070525 20150807
200716619510161 1661951 20070526 20090417
200816385110263 1638511 20080514 20170629
200816385110267 1638511 20080806 20170127
200816385110268 1638511 20080827 20170725
200816385110276 1638511 20081112 20121120
200816386010531 1638881 20080207 20130314
200816386010532 1637551 20080213 20131107
200816386010533 1638601 20080213 20120224  60 20100928 20101019  2
200816386010543 1638601 20080305 20100901
200816386010544 1638601 20080306 20101015
200816386010546 1638921 20080311 20160113
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help. I had not thought of using .true. and .false.